# the use of would and conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

I'd like to construct a sentence, but I just can't decide if it's incorrect, or correct.

The sentence is

> If you wouldn't remind me to breathe, I would be dead for years.

It's a part of a conversation, where person A often acts like person B's walking conscience, and person B is quite annoyed by that, so he sarcastically says that if he wouldn't be reminded to breathe, he'd already be dead, mocking person A for his motherlike reminders, which person B doesn't think necessary.

"If you didn't remind to breathe, I would be dead for years" sounds quite off to me, but since I'm not a native speaker, obviously I can be mistaken and that's why I'd like to ask for help.

Please help me out, I feel so uncertain.

Comment: If you make the description of what you are trying to say longer and more detailed, then I think it might help users understand how to help you.

Comment: That sentence is almost certainly wrong--it doesn't appear to fit any natural situation--so as Max says, we need to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "If you hadn't reminded me to breathe then I would now have been dead for many years"?

Comment: Well, it's a part of a conversation, where person A often acts like person B's walking conscience, and person B is quite annoyed by that, so he sarcastically says that if he wouldn't be reminded to breathe, he'd already be dead, mocking person A for his motherlike reminders, which person B doesn't think necessary. I hope this clears things up?

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of description that you should include in all of your posts.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first time here, but I will pay attention to details in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @user38210 Try: "I'd have died years ago if you hadn't reminded me to breathe." Or: "I'd have died years ago if you hadn't nagged me to breathe." (In both, "I'd" is a contraction of "I would.")

Comment: I would say, `If you hadn't reminded me to breathe, I would have been dead years ago`

Answer (score 1):

The standard verb form for the protasis of a counterfactual conditional is the so-called "past subjunctive" (which is identical to the past except for the single word 'were'), so

> If you didn't remind me to breathe ...

is the standard form, and the only possible one for many speakers (including me).

There is, though, a fairly common dialectal variation which substitutes "would":

> If you wouldn't remind me to breathe ...

I would not say this, but many people would. My impression is that this is a distictively American form, but I haven't researched it.

Answer (score 0):

If s/he's being sarcastic it might be:

"I'd be dead if you didn't remind me to breathe."

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers, it helped me a lot, I think I'll go with the last one!

Answer (score 0):

Native NAmE speaker here...I'd say something like "If you didn't keep reminding me to breathe, I'd have been dead years ago."

Answer (score 0):

It's purely an unreal or hypothetical situation in the past; the sentence should be conditional type 3 as follows:

If you had not reminded me to breathe, I would have been dead for years now.